# Relational Algebra Join - necessary to rename?

Tags: join, database-design, relational-algebra, relational

Let's assume i have some 2 simple tables:

**IMPORTANT: This is about relational algebra, not SQL.**

Band table:

```
 band_name founded
 Gambo     1975
 John.     1342
```

Album table:

```
album_name band_name
Celsius.   Gambo
Trambo     Gambo
```

Now, since the Band and the Album table share the same column name "band_name", would it be necessary to rename it when i would join them?

As far as i know, the join eliminates the duplicate entry that is shared amongst the join. This example, where i simply pick all Bands that are existing in the Album table (obviously just 'Gambo' in this giving example)

```
Πfounded, band_name(Band ⋈ Album)
```

should therefore work fine, right? Can somebody confirm?

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Have to enter a caveat that there are many variants of Relational Algebra; that they differ in semantics; and they differ in syntax. Assuming you intend a variant similar to that in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) ...)

Yes that expression should work fine. The natural join operator `⋈` matches same-named attributes between its two operands. So the subexpression `Band ⋈ Album` produces a result with attributes `{band_name, founded, album_name}`. Your expression projects two of those.

Note the attributes for a relation value are a *set* not a sequence; therefore any operation over relation operands with same-named attributes must match attributes.

In contrast, Cartesian Product `×` requires its operands to have disjoint attribute names. Then `Band × Album` is ill-formed and would be rejected. (So you'd need to Rename `band_name` in one of them, to get relations that could be operands.)

I'm not all that happy with your way of putting it "the join eliminates the duplicate entry that is shared amongst the join." Because only in SQL do you get a duplicate (from `SELECT * FROM Band, Album ...` -- which results in a table with four columns, of which two are named `band_name`). SQL `FROM` list of tables is a botch-up: neither join nor Cartesian Product, but something trying to be both, and succeeding only in being neither. RA's `⋈` never produces a "duplicate" so never does it "eliminate" anything.

Particularly if there's Keys declared and a Foreign Key constraint (from `Album`'s `band_name` to `Band`'s) I see those as identifying the *same* band, then the natural operation is to bring together that which has been taken apart, so the name 'Natural Join'.

Comment: The wikipedia Relational algebra article Natural join section contains the misleading "If this is not the case such as in the foreign key from Dept.Manager to Employee.Name then we have to rename these columns before we take the natural join." (Followed by the incorrect "Such a join [...] is an equijoin.) The entire paragraph it's in is misconceived & very poorly worded. I wonder if this is the source of the "necessary to rename" confusion in the (unclear) question. Whether "we have to rename" depends on argument & result tuple membership criteria, not FKs or shared or unshared columns per se.